# Transitioning to Ubuntu

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, ntfs

I am currently running Windows 7 with 2 hard drives.

- An SSD where the OS and apps are stored.
- A HDD which stores all my videos, music, files. (NTFS)

If I was to format the SSD and install Ubuntu, would I still be able to connect my HDD with all the media and files still on it?

I only ask this in case Linux uses a different native filesystem compared to windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can install Linux on the SSD (or on a partition on your OS so you can have both Windows and Ubuntu on that SSD) and access the HDD with the NTFS filesystem.

I recommend that you use the HDD for reading (or even mount it read-only) since the permissions will be different. (NTFS and windows use ACL, which differs from traditional linux UGO rights, but just reading the files should not be any problem).

Comment: but are you saying that I won't be able to add more media onto the drive?

Comment: You will be able to write to it, but permission will be different. So I do not recommend installing programs on it or using it as as /home. Just accessing it (e.g. reading movies, adding new movies etc) will work just fine.